# HD video is slower than audio output

Tags: windows-7, media-player, high-definition

I have an HD video files (1920x1080 H.264 DUAL AUDIO FLAC)
file type: MKV
file size: 1.25 GB
file length: 24 minutes

the problem is the video output is not synchronized with audio output,
something slow too much sometime it gets too fast

I tried running it on Windows Media Player , Media Player Classic , and a few other players,
but the result is the same

Additional Info:
for device information I'm on [LG S510 labtop](http://www.notebookreview.com/default.asp?newsID=4761)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main problem is the graphic processing capability of your computer.

Try upgrading your graphics card, or try playing that video on an 1GB Nvidia.

Comment: so it not a player issue .......
, and i need a new graphics adapter, OK thanks.